# Gather all Feature objects returned by Async methods

Tags: spring, asynchronous, aop, aspectj, future

I am using Spring Framework stack, and I'm trying to realise the following feature.

**I want to store in some map, every 'Feature' object returned by @Async methods.**

So far I managed to write an Aspect, registering on such method, but, it does not get the asynchronic 'Feature' proxy, but it gets already the result of this method - value returned when method finishes. So aspect @AfterReturning registers not for returning a proxy, but real value after method finish. So far I have discovered that if I would have another object, which just executes my @Async method, and forwards the resulting Feature, then registering for that Future, gets the Future (proxy) I want. But it's a troublesome solution to have another objects which proxies calls to every async method.

```
@Component
public class Sample {
    @Async
    @MyAnnotation
    public Future<Integer> run() {
        // long running operation
        return new AsyncResult(10);
    }
}

@Component
@Aspect
public class SampleAspect {

 @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(myAnnotation )", returning = "retVal")
    public Object process(Object retVal, String reqId, MyAnnotation myAnnotation ) throws Throwable {
        // method execution has already finished here
        // retval is instanceof AsyncResult, I want it to be a Future proxy
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Workaround requiring additional object

```
@Component
public class OtherSample {
    @Autowired Sample sample;

    @OtherAnnotation
    public Futgure<Integer> run() {
        return sample.run();
    }
}


@Component
@Aspect
public class OtherAspect {

 @AfterReturning(pointcut = "@annotation(otherAnnotation)", returning = "retVal")
    public Object process(Object retVal, String reqId, OtherAnnotation otherAnnotation ) throws Throwable {
        // method execution has NOT finished here
        // retval is instanceof Future proxy
        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code. It'll be easier to understand than a description.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have added already the code samples :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer to your question but it's a proposition of a workaround.

Creating aspects for @Async annotated methods is a quite specific situation. Couldn't you just create a dedicated implementation of **org.springframework.core.task.AsyncTaskExecutor**?

Here is an [simple configuration](http://pastie.org/8558394) from my previous project. I used it to handle (log) exceptions thrown from tasks.